# Ionic3: Cannot declare InAppBrowser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, inappbrowser

I want to use InAppBrowser to open all **target blank** links. I follow the documentation and I always get an error when I declare the plugin on constructor:

> Can't resolve all parameters for MyApp: (?, ?, ?).

This error appears to me when I put `private iab: InAppBrowser` on constructor.

**My code:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})


export class HomePage {

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public plt: Platform, private iab: InAppBrowser) {

    this.plt.ready().then((readySource) => {
        console.log("Ready!");
        window.open = this.iab.open;
    });
  }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    InAppBrowser,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Someone knows whats it can be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good, so the problem seems to be because of the `@ionic-native/core` version that your project uses.

As you can see **[in the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/#Installation)** the Ionic team has updated the Ionic Native commands in order to avoid this error:

> **Installation**
>
> To add Ionic Native to your app, run following command to install the core package: 
>   `npm install @ionic-native/core@4 --save`

And...

> **Usage**
>
> Install the Needed Plugins
>   Install the Ionic Native package for each plugin you want to add.
>   For example, if you want to install the Camera plugin, you will need to run the following command:
>
> `npm install @ionic-native/camera@4 --save`
>
> Then install the plugin using Cordova or Ionic CLI. For example:
>
> `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`

Notice the **@4** in both commands. That allows you to install the right version of the Ionic Native dependencies even if you're using the new CLI.

---

**TLDR;** So if you installed the plugin using the **@4** you can import it like this: `import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';`

If not, you may be using a newer version of Ionic Native so you need to import it like this: `import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx'`

Comment: @FernandoAureliano could you please paste the content of your `app.module.ts` file in your question?

Comment: I put it on app.module.ts, but I got the same error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyApp: (?, ?, ?).      :(

Comment: Your code looks fine... Maybe it's a silly question, but have you already tried by stopping the app and running `ionic serve` again?

Comment: I did it now and I got:  Browse...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NgModule'. Types of property 'providers' are 
[app-scripts]             incompatible. Type '(typeof SplashScreen | InAppBrowserOriginal | { provide: typeof ErrorHandler; useClass: 
[app-scripts]             typeof Io...' is not assignable to type 'Provider[]'. Type 'typeof SplashScreen | InAppBrowserOriginal | {

Comment: Does it work if you change both imports to be `import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx'; (notice the ending ngx at the end)`?

Comment: I think it is just for ionic4

Comment: @FernandoAureliano I've updated the answer including some more details about the cause of the issue :)